# Problems with sending string array/list through query string

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a string array to the bing translate api, which I have received and encoded as UTF-8.
However, when I make the call with the variable the service spits out an error:

"There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String[]. Encountered unexpected character 'ï'."

If I manually add the string array as a string not within a variable, it works. I'm using the Requests module, so I'm thinking it's encoding the url... I have no idea.

```
class getLanguages(apiFunctions):
    def GET(self):
        #get the access token
        data = self.accessToken()
        token = data['access_token']

        codes = self.getCodes(token)
        languageNames = self.getLanguageNames(token,codes)


        codesList = ast.literal_eval(codes)

        return languageNames + codes

    def getCodes(self,token):
        url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate'
        auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
        r = requests.get(url, headers=auth_header)
        return r.text.encode('utf-8')

    def getLanguageNames(self,token,codes):
        url = 'http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/GetLanguageNames'

        #this is where I add the language codes string to the query

        payload = {'locale': 'en', 'languageCodes': codes}
        auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
        r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=auth_header)

        return r.text.encode('utf-8')
```

And this is the string:

```
["ar","bg","ca","zh-CHS","zh-CHT","cs","da","nl","en","et","fi","fr","de","el","ht","he","hi","mww","hu","id","it","ja","tlh","tlh-Qaak","ko","lv","lt","ms","mt","no","fa","pl","pt","ro","ru","sk","sl","es","sv","th","tr","uk","ur","vi","cy"]
```

Comment: That string is set to variable codes?

Comment: Yes, that string is sent back in the getCodes function.

Comment: params is for query parameters, i.e., what you would have is your `url` + `?locale=en&languageCodes=...`. What are you expecting `languageCodes` to be?

Comment: If i enter "['en']" in the payload everything works as expected, but if i have the codes variable there it doesnt. To my knowledge they should be the same as they are formatted identically. Perhaps, that codes var is encoded differently...